# Android DDMS is blank

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ddms

I am trying to open DDMS from tools folder in android sdk (monitor), but it just show blank view and then freeze
[image]

`java -version` result:

```
➜  ~ java -version
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: While it looks like a MacOS, it will help others if you list what version of MacOS you are running along with version of Android Studio and Android SDK.

Comment: osx version 10.13.2 (HighSierra), Android studio 2.2

Comment: Android Studio 2.2 dates back to late 2016: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2016/12/this-is-minor-update-to-android-studio-2.html If you've been updating the SDK, then do update Android Studio as I don't believe full backward testing is done between the two. See [Android Studio 3.0 release announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fixed the issue via downgrading the jdk from jdk-8u161-macosx-x64 to jdk-8u151-macosx-x64

Comment: This helped me. Thanks :)